# Delete records from (many to many) result table with Entity Framework and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a `Role` and a `Permision` table, with a many-to-many relationship. I want to remove some rows from result table (`RolePermission`) which doesn't exist as a class in my project :

```
 public class RoleDto
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PermissionDto> Permissions { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class Permission
 {
        public Permission()
        {
            this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to delete some records from the `RolePermission` table in my database:

[image]

I tried this solution but it's not working :

```
    public void setRolePermissions(int role, List<int> permissions)
    {
        if (permissions.Count > 0 && role != 0)
        {
            var model = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == role);

            foreach (int item in permissions)
            {
                Permission permission = (Permission)getPermissionsByid(item);
                model.Permissions.Remove(permission);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should explicitly load the related entities and then call Remove method.

```
public void setRolePermissions(int role, List<int> permissions)
{
    var roleToUpdate = _context.Roles.Find(role);
    _context.Entry(roleToUpdate).Collection("Permissions").Load(); // load explicitly here
    foreach (int item in permissions)
    {
        Permission permission = (Permission)getPermissionsByid(item);
        roleToUpdate.Permissions.Remove(permission);
    }    

    _context.SaveChanges();
{}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Did you explicitly load all the related entities?

Comment: i loded just Permission entite !

Comment: Hi @AHmédNet, glad you made it work. Could you please mark it as answered? Many thanks!

Comment: how can we explicitly load that manytomany table since we doesn't have access to that table